# Intentional kernel panic under Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-panic

Is there any way to cause a kernel panic under Linux? I've heard of

`echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

but it seems to just freeze, and I'm not sure it's a kernel panic. Is there any C program I can run as root to cause a kernel panic?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek just to experiment. Although I imagine it could be useful to kernel developers.

Comment: You could load a kernel module which immediately tries to dereference NULL. That should give a fairly safe kernel panic. Or you could just have the module call panic. A kernel panic isn't just one, solitary thing—its a whole range of errors. You're asking something similar to "is there some way I can make a program crash?"

Comment: the sysrq method does create a kernel crash, but you probably don't have anything set up to handle the crashdump, and you aren't looking at the console where the crash information is sent.

Comment: @derobert Dereferencing NULL will give an Oops which only ends up being a panic if the kernel is configured as such (`CONFIG_PANIC_ON_OOPS=y`). To trigger a panic... simply load a module that calls `panic()`!

Comment: Kernel panic can also be achieved by using `sh` as init and then typing `exit`.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Oh, inducing this by force can be a great technique for people who use the kernel in embedded applications. Think of copy-protection mechanisms, respectively people using counterfeit / illegally modified hardware. The whole *thinking* behind to me seems very 80s, though: it reminds me of CBM Amiga times when they caused the "Guru" to blink if some copy protection was bypassed in erroneous (i. e. amateurish) ways ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### using kill

I think you could try the following:

```
$ kill -6 1
```

This sends signal # 6 to process #1 (the init process). If you read up in the signals man page: ["man 7 signals"](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal):

```
   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                                 or death of controlling process
   SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
   SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
   SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
   SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
```

You can find out how a process wants to handle the various signals (`cat /proc/$PID/status`). See this U&L Q&A for more info: [How can I check what signals a process is listening to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to).

#### overflowing memory

Another method is to overflow memory to induce a kernel panic. First you'll need to disable swap.

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01         partition   14352376    3177812 -1

$ swapoff /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
```

Now to consume all the memory:

```
$ for r in /dev/ram*; do cat /dev/zero > $r; done
```

#### References

- [How to force a Linux kernel panic](http://archive.geekworld.co.za/node/277)
- [How can I check what signals a process is listening to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to)

Comment: Weird. The first time, it seemed to "pause" xorg. My music stopped, and I saw the cli login you normally get when you change TTYs. I logged in and then switched back to tty7 (xorg), and the second time it did the same thing as echoing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger`. I guess you have to be in a tty to see the error information. And for the loop that consumes all memory, `cat` gets a write error saying the device is full, but the kernel must take care of it, becuase if I check my RAM, only ~300MB is used.

Comment: Actually, PID 1 is explicitly protected from signals it's not set up to catch.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7441

Comment: @Jander - thanks. Is there a way to get a list of the signals that init is setup to catch?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sudo kill -SEGV 1`. This will immediately crash init as if there were MM fault(kernel equivalent of segment violation).

Answer (score 0):

Some intel hardware have a NMI button (Non-maskable interrupt) that will immediately cause a panic, if you've got the [NMI watchdog enabled](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/nmi_watchdog.txt).  There are a couple other ways to cause the NMI watchdog to panic as well