# killall firefox does not kill firefox

Tags: firefox, kill, process-management

When I had loads of firefox windows open and wanted to close them quickly I did 
`killall firefox`
using `killall` from the `psmisc` package in Ubuntu.

Nothing happened.

I looked in the list of my processes and there were many lines of the form

```
alle_meije     55061    7662  0 01:16 ?        00:00:31 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 126 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 9704 -prefMapSize 254479 -jsInitLen 279340 -parentBuildID 20220106144528 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7662 true tab
```

so, `firefox` being the 'basename' of the executable there, I would have expected these to be killed.

Sure enough, doing it by hand using
`kill $( ps -fu $USER | grep firefox | awk '{print $2}' )`
did close all these windows. Does anyone know why the same does not happen with `killall`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does killall command kill only one instance of the process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257666/why-does-killall-command-kill-only-one-instance-of-the-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`killall firefox-bin` works for me but then I use the [official](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) Firefox distribution.

As mentioned in the comments, `pkill -f firefox` should work as well.

---

> `-f` The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command line is used.

Comment: Thanks, this does work. The strange thing is, killall now works as well (in a new login). Finding a way to kill the windows was not the problem, I just wondered what could cause this. The only possible cause I have come up with is that previously, I had done suspend/continue a few times. As to how, no idea...

Answer (score -4):

When I want to kill all of a specific process I use this script. I am sure there are better ways. But it works for things like `firefox-esr`. `firefox-bin`, `firefox`. Processes that are basically identical but may have different names. Be careful though, you can kill processes you don't want!

```
ps -e | grep <process name> | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs kill
```

In your case:

```
ps -e | grep firefox | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: Why so complicated? I'm giving -1. In addition, it uses 4 different programs to achieve such a simplistic job...

Comment: On my system, at least, `ps -e` does not report `firefox` but instead shows it as `GeckoMain`. More importantly, and as you point out, this can kill completely unrelated processes!

Comment: @terdon The more you know!

Comment: Have a look at `pgrep -f` and `pkill -f`, those will be better tools for this sort of thing.